# Append Incremental Number to Class in While Loop

Tags: php

I have a standard while loop. I want to append an Incremental number to a class within the while loop.  So the while loop is:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newNominee))
{
print "<tr><td><input type='search' class='nameSearch" name='voteNominee[]' placeholder='Search User' value='$nomName' /></td></tr>";
}
```

So when the while loop runs through I want the class nameSearch to append:

```
nameSearch_1
nameSearch_2
nameSearch_3 and so on..
```

I've tried adding i=0; before the while loop and then:

```
class="nameSearch_'+ i +'"
```

And then i++ after the while loop but that isn't doing the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: You almost had it! In PHP the variables are defined with a **$** symbol, so *i* is in fact always `$i` and are concatenated with `.` rather than `+`.  The answers below should give you more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look over quotes around the values

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($newNominee))
{
   echo "<tr><td><input type='search' class='nameSearch_$i' name='voteNominee[]' placeholder='Search User' value='$nomName' /></td></tr>";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: This could be better, the variables should be escaped from the string sequence such as `echo " string ".$var." end string" ;` . Also it would be useful to explain the OP why his usage of `+` as a concatenater was incorrect.

Comment: Yes you're right @Martin I'll but lately. Did you downvoted the answer